# Решение задачи по поиску года с максимальным количеством жителей

Tags: java

Добрый. Очень нужна помощь, в программировании совсем новичок и возник затор с задачкой.
Задача: вывести год, в который жило максимальное количество людей. Дата рождения и дата смерти произвольные значения.

Вот что имею пока:

```
public class Main {
static List<Human> list = new ArrayList();
int year;
Human human;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int birthDay;
    int LifeLeight;
    Human human = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

        human = new Human();
        int min = 1880;
        int max = 1990;
        int LifeLeightMin = 35;
        int LifeLeightMax = 150;
        boolean isLife = true;

        birthDay = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

        human.setBirthDay(birthDay);

        LifeLeight = (int) (Math.random() * (LifeLeightMax - LifeLeightMin) 
        + LifeLeightMin);

        human.setDeathDay(human.getBirthDay() + LifeLeight);
        System.out.println(human);
        countMaxLives();
    }

 }
```

И дальше не могу сообразить, как правильно сделать список всех лет жизни у каждого человека и засунуть все это в Map, что бы потом посчитать максимальное значение по Value.

Help...please

Comment: 2017, очевидно же

Comment: Для начала вам нужно создать `Map<Human> humanMap = new HashMap<Human>();`
После, в каждой итерации сохранять в мапу человека `humanMap.put(human);`

Answer (score 2):

Дурацкий вариант "в лоб"

```
//В качестве ключа год, в качестве значения - количество живущих в нем
Map<Integer, Integer> years = new HashMap();
for(int i = min; i <= max; i++){
    years.put(i, 0);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    birthDay = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    human.setBirthDay(birthDay);
    LifeLenght = (int) (Math.random() * (LifeLeightMax - LifeLeightMin) 
        + LifeLenghtMin);

    human.setDeathDay(human.getBirthDay() + LifeLeight);
     //Добавляем по единичке к каждому году, в котором живет данный индивидум
    for(int j = birthDay; j <= LifeLenght + birthDay; j++){
        years.put(j, years.get(j) + 1);
    }
}
//Ищем ключ(год) с максимальным значением. Тут я схалтурю и скопипащу решение для Java 8
Integer year = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
```

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Text_processing/Max_licenses_in_use#Java

Answer (score 2):

`countMaxLives();` нужно вызвать после заполнения списка людей - замените этот вызов на `list.add(human);`
После наполнения списка, можно развернуть его в список лет, в которые каждый человек жил, и затем определить наиболее часто встречаемый год.
Если достаточно получить хотя бы один из годов, когда количество живущих было максимальным, то можно сделать так:

```
private static int countMaxLives() {
    return Collections.max(list.parallelStream()
                   .map(h -> IntStream.range(h.birthDay, h.deathDay))
                   .flatMapToInt(Function.identity()).boxed() //здесь имеем стрим с годами жизни
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .getKey();

}
```

Если необходимо получить все максимальные года, то необходимо переписать и возвращать список лет с максимальным количеством людей:

```
private static List<Integer> countMaxLives(){
    return Collections.max(list.parallelStream()
                   .map(h -> IntStream.range(h.birthDay, h.deathDay))
                   .flatMapToInt(Function.identity()).boxed() //здесь имеем стрим с годами жизни
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) //здесь map <год -> количество людей>
                                   .entrySet().parallelStream()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList()))) // здесь map <количество людей -> года>
                                   .entrySet(),
               Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .getValue();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! буду пробовать